# pact-jvm create pact manually by hand

Tags: java, pact, pact-jvm

I'm exploring the chance to use pact-jvm with a client and provider that already exist and that are working productively.
Currently I try to create a pact file per hand and verify it for the provider. I wonder if this even makes sense. I fear maybe I didn't get the point.
Is this okay or am I off the track?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For clarify sake, are you saying you've creating the pact contract by hand?  The JSON that specifies all interactions between the consumer and the provider?

Comment: Indeed, actually I'm trying to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, creating the contract by hand - that is, manually crafting a JSON document according to the pact specification - is an anti-pattern in Pact.

We often see people using Pact where there are existing integrations, the first step is creating the consumer tests in the consumer code base and getting it to publish the pacts. Even just for a subset of its functionality to begin with.

Then you can look to verify it with the provider. Eventually, you add more and more tests until the complete functionality is covered at which point, you can remove any existing or invalidated E2E suites!

Comment: To add to this, you can do it by hand, but why would you if you can do it in code instead?  It will also future proof your contract for the immediate future if we decide to change the schema/format of it.  All you have to do is run the code that generates your interactions and output them :)